# Beginner to sqlite trying to improve performance through database design, 'join' and 'where'

Tags: sqlite, join

I have a large table (potentially millions of rows) that in its naive form would contain lots of repetition, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    salesperson TEXT,
    customer    TEXT
);

INSERT INTO sales VALUES(NULL, "Rod", "Acme");
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(NULL, "Jane", "Xyz Corp");
INSERT INTO sales VALUES(NULL, "Freddy", "Acme");
<... many more lines containing significant repetitions of each salesperson and each customer >
```

I think I know enough that this is not the ideal approach when I want to perform queries such as:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sales WHERE salesperson="Jane";
```

So my database should be rearranged as:

```
CREATE TABLE sales(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    salesperson INTEGER,
    customer    INTEGER
);

CREATE TABLE salespeople(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name        TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE customers(
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name        TEXT
);
```

In reality there are many more columns in the single-table solution, and therefore more distinct tables in the normalized (if that's even the right use of the term) version.

I've timed tests of a dumb query against the single-table v.s. a JOIN with a WHERE against the split-tables version and the "smart" version is about 25% slower, so clearly I'm missing something:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sales INNER JOIN salespeople ON sales.salesperson=salespeople.id WHERE salespeople.name="Freddy";
```

If I lookup the salesperson.id first as a separate query, I see times ~33% faster than the dumb implementation (which is less than I was hoping for).

```
SELECT id FROM salespeople WHERE name="Freddy";
```

...then

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sales WHERE salesperson=previouslyLookedUpId;
```

I get the impression that the WHERE (in the multi-table solution) is being evaluated for every row, rather than once to determine the relevant salesperson id, as intended. Clearly my queries (or constraints, or indices?) aren't allowing the db engine to work efficiently.

I only know enough to know that I don't know enough... What is the right approach here?

Comment: In your SALES table, do you have an index on salespersonid and also one on customerid?

Comment: No. Is that achieved as part of the 'CREATE TABLE', or separately?

Comment: CREATE INDEX: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html

Comment: Also, if the SALESPERSON table contained many rows, you'd want an index on SALESPEOPLE.name column.  You want indexes on the foreign key columns and on the column(s) you filter by most often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, see my comment about indexes.

Second, the goal of "normalizing" a database design is not performance. Often it is the case that a normalized design will perform more slowly than a denormalized or "flattened" table. Joins can be expensive in terms of resource consumption.

The goal of normalizing is the proper representation of the entities and their relationships; if your domain is accurately mapped to a normalized design it is impossible to get different answers to the same question. That's the goal.

Also, a normalized design is extensible. That is another major virtue and goal.

Since you use the word "smart".  A normalized design is "simple-minded", not smart, though it takes smarts to attain simplicity.

P.S.

What kind of performance do you get, relative to a standard join, with this approach:

```
                 from sales
                 where salespersonid = (select id from SALESPEOPLE where name = 'Joe')
```

when SALESPEOPLE.name and salespersonid are indexed?

or this:

```
                ... from sales
                inner join
                (select id from SALESPEOPLE where name = 'Joe') as MYPEEPS
                on sales.salespersonid = MYPEEPS.id
```

Comment: I was expecting performance to increase (in this case at least) as the 'WHERE' becomes an integer match rather than a string match.

Comment: `I only know enough to know that I don't know enough.` Bear this in mind.  Your expectation is not unreasonable, but the join itself has overhead. Performance varies and will depend on the size of the table, the cardinality of the indexes, etc etc, and primarily on whether an operation is CPU-intensive or DISK-intensive. Disk-intensive operations are orders-of-magnitude slower than most CPU-intensive operations. A comparison is a CPU issue and is therefore very low on the list of optimizations.

Comment: That said, you are going in the right direction as far as normalization is concerned, by creating the SALESPERSON and CUSTOMER tables and using integer foreign keys.

Comment: OK, I've added some indices and now the speed is inline with my rough expectations - the JOINed query now takes ~16% of the time of the big flat (but still un-indexed) table. I need to spend some time tinkering to understand what matters.

Comment: I do still have a question though, regarding the reasons behind the original performance deltas. Since the JOINed query was so much slower than the sequential "lookup the ID then do a plain SELECT" solution, is the JOIN query badly written such that the WHERE is evaluated more often (once per sales row) than necessary (just once)? If I'd put a constraint on salesperson.name being unique, would that have helped the db engine to only do the comparison once?

Comment: To reinforce the above uncertainty, putting an index on sales.salesperson in the big flat table model makes it faster than the JOINed version. It's quite satisfying seeing the scale of speedups that are possible, but still a black art (to me) as to how best to achieve that. And I'm convinced the WHERE is still being worked harder than necessary.

Comment: To determine how a specific data engine optimizes using available indexes, one typically resorts to asking the engine to explain itself. In SQlite, you do this: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html

Comment: And you can read here to learn more about how SQlite uses indexes in WHERE clauses: http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html  -- once you understand that, it will have become a white art from a black art.

Comment: See especially the section on `subquery flattening`.

Comment: The two alternative queries suggested produce the same performance, give or take. The first is very clean (and I can't believe I wasn't already doing that for my "get the ID first up-front" method. Speed is almost doubled.

Comment: I'm not sure if Tim meant to imply that the surrogate key/integer-as-foreign-key approach is "more normalized," but if so, I disagree. What's important is to figure out what it takes to identify a person uniquely. If two people can have the same first name, you can include their last name too. And if two people can have the same compound name, you can include their employee number, or some other disambiguating value. Best, though, is if the value is relevant to the domain at hand. Using could-be-random integers as IDs does not count as normalization. Instead, think of functional dependencies.

Comment: No, I didn't intend to imply that the datatype had anything to do with the concept of Normalization in the abstract. We agree. But from a `practical` point of view, on the other hand, integers make excellent primary keys because they're simple to use: a single column suffices to confer uniqueness upon the entity represented by the tuple, and a single integer is very easy to use as a foreign key. Until recently many middleware/providers did not support composite keys well or at all. But that's a practical, not a conceptual, concern. BUt so is performance :-)

Comment: Fair enough, Tim. The *every-key-has-to-be-an-integer* impulse is more often taught than understood, so I felt compelled to probe. No fight necessary!